# How to get exact width and height of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here i am going to ask two questions...

how to get the exact width of the div

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert("Width of div: " + $("#a").width());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a" style="width:1000px;height:500px;">
<div style="height:100px;width:300px;padding:10px;margin:3px;border:1px solid blue;background-color:lightblue;">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>Display the width of div</button>

</body>
</html>
```

here i am declared 2 .. parent div width is 1000 child div width is 300 if i use  $("#a").width() function i will get 1000 which i mentioned on that div. but how can i get the exact used width(300) using $("#a") as well as same in height?

Answer (score 1):

your "a" is 1000px - since you want the width of the div within the "a" you need to use:

```
$("#a div").width()
```

or if you can have multiple divs - then use :first (or some other selector)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` methods like

```
$("button").click(function(){
    alert("Width of div: " + $("#a div").attr("width"));
  });
```

Comment: And where, precisely, is the `width` attribute used in the posted html?

Answer (score 0):

Try with chaining in jquery

```
$("#a div").width()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this code to get the height and width div inside  #a div

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert("Width of div: " + $("#a div").width());
    alert("Width of div: " + $("#a div").height());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have only two divs, then why dont you just assign id to your second div also.

```
<div id="a" style="width:1000px;height:500px;">
<div id="b" style="height:100px;width:300px;padding:10px;margin:3px;border:1px solid blue;background-  color:lightblue;">
</div>
</div>
```

Then you can just get the width and height as follows:

```
var width = $('#b').attr("width");
var height = $('#b').attr("height");
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.. but i think it's not a generic solution.. if they used more than div how can we find the exact width.. as well traversing it's not a generic

Comment: That's why I explicitly mentioned that if you would have only divs, then you may go with this approach.